# Importing modules from a parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

So I have my project as

```
->Main
-->Module1
------>__init__.py
------>Module1.py
-->Module2
------>__init__.py
------>Module2.py
```

I want to import Module1.py's class in Module2.py

What I have tried is:

```
from ..Module1 import Module1
from Module1 import Module1
```

And both of them do not seem to solve it.

> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: use absolute path

Comment: try : from Main.Module1 import Module1

Comment: Are you using a virtual env and/or setting the PYTHONPATH env var? You don't show an `__init__.py` file in `Main/` so it's not clear if you expect your top level package to be `Main` or to have `Module1` and `Module2` as 2 separate top level packages.

Comment: What's the error message for the second (absolute) import ?

Comment: As a general rule: to be importable, a module or package must be in a directory which is in your `sys.path`.  In this case, it means that you need "/path/to/Main" to be in your `sys.path`. There are various way to get this result, which one you want depends on the context.